# Javascript file is not working on my ruby on rails app

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails

How can I call javascript file in my ruby on rails website.
For example I have this file and its inside projectname/app/assets/javascripts/bootstrap.js

Here what I tried and all of them are wrong

```
 <script src="~/app/assets/javascripts/bootstrap.js"></script>
  <script src="/assets/javascripts/bootstrap.js"></script>
  <script src="../javascripts/bootstrap.js"></script>
```

I got this error

```
(index):607 GET http://localhost:3000/~/app/assets/javascripts/bootstrap.js net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found)
```

in my application.html.erb

```
<%= javascript_pack_tag 'application' %>
```

Comment: The `pack_tag` is used for webpacker.  If you are just trying to link to the file you can put it inside your public directory and then just link to the path `/folder_name/file_name.js` something like that.  So, for example `/public/javascripts/bootstrap.js` and then (I believe) in your view file `<script src="/javascripts/bootstrap.js"></script>`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you are using webpack, you need to import all the JS files into your application.js

In your application.html.erb you got:

```rb
<%= javascript_pack_tag 'application' %>
```

So it is expecting that you have application.js inside `app/javascript/packs`

Inside that file you can include the bootstrap.js

So you can make a dir: `app/javascript/bootstrap` and place your bootstrap.js inside that folder. Than you can include it inside your application.js

```js
# app/javascript/packs/application.js
import "../bootstrap/bootstrap";
```